# Should we use 'use' if we only call a function once?

Tags: php, performance

Is it bad to use the keyword `use` even though we only call a function once?
E.g. I have my own typo3 extension, and I am accessing a typo3 core function in my controller, but only once.

```
$message = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
```

I could also make use of `use`:

```
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
...
$message = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
```

In my opinion the second variant is much cleaner, but are there any performance issues if I make use of `use` only for one call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, there should be no performance hit. You're calling a function (and thus an autoloader) either way (which is where any performance hit will be).

To explain why, your `use` statement is simply an alias. Your autoloader will do the same work either way. And it will likely be opcode cached, so any performance hit (we're talking milliseconds here, if that) will only be on the first run.

Answer (score 2):

It's much cleaner to import the classes and then use `::class` to reference them e.g...

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage;

$message = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MailMessage::class);
```

Comment: Im not sure that indirect reference is more readable than direct one. It's only a matter of taste IMO.

Comment: In IDE's (like phpstorm) this makes it really easy to jump into that class. As a string it won't recognise it.

Answer (score 1):

I particularly prefer the second choice too. And there is no performance hit. You can use the second one without any concern.

Answer (score -1):

First option is faster when in namespace context and it could be more readable because of FQNS (it's a matter of taste). When there is a lot of "imports" 
it may indicate too high a degree of dependence and break of the single responsibility principle. So I often use inline namespacing using FQNS.

> Optimizing PHP performance by using fully-qualified function calls
>   https://veewee.github.io/blog/optimizing-php-performance-by-fq-function-calls/

Try to profile your code to get the answer.

Comment: How do you know the first is faster? Do you have anything to support this?

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).